# Trying to set up OpenVPN server on a vps

Tags: vpn, vps, openvpn, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to set up an OpenVPN server on my VPS for myself when I'm in public places, using this tutorial, http://tipupdate.com/how-to-install-openvpn-on-ubuntu-vps/

However whenever I try to start the server, it gives me this,

```
root@vps:~# /etc/init.d/openvpn start
 * Starting virtual private network daemon(s)...                                                                 *   Autostarting VPN 'server'                                                                           [fail]
```

The log contains this

```
Tue Dec 11 10:53:32 2012 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 1024 bit key
Tue Dec 11 10:53:32 2012 /usr/bin/openssl-vulnkey -q -b 1024 -m <modulus omitted>
Tue Dec 11 10:53:33 2012 TLS-Auth MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Tue Dec 11 10:53:33 2012 ROUTE: default_gateway=UNDEF
Tue Dec 11 10:53:33 2012 Note: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)
Tue Dec 11 10:53:33 2012 Note: Attempting fallback to kernel 2.2 TUN/TAP interface
Tue Dec 11 10:53:33 2012 Cannot allocate TUN/TAP dev dynamically
Tue Dec 11 10:53:33 2012 Exiting
```

So obviously it's something to do with the tun, but I don't understand how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using an OpenVZ-based VPS provider. The provider must enable TUN/TAP in your container before you will be able to use OpenVPN (or anything else that relies on TUN/TAP).

Answer (score 5):

You have not `/dev/net/tun` node in your `/dev` directory.

Try to create it:

```
cd /dev
mkdir net
cd net
mknod tun c 10 200
chmod 666 tun
```

Or you can try, according to [this article](http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/), use this command: `openvpn --mktun`

If will openvpn still complain about non-existent tun interface, try use `modprobe tun` command. But on mine Ubuntu have kernel support for `tun` interface compiled in.

Comment: `modprobe tun` did it for me, Debian Jessie.

Comment: Does not work on an OpenVZ VPS, the error will change to `Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: Operation not permitted`